# Oracle MV requires object type to be defined as FINAL?

Tags: oracle, materialized-view, inheritance, user-defined-type

I want to create an Oracle 18c **materialized view (MV)** on a table that has a user-defined datatype called [ST_GEOMETRY](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm):

- The MV would do a COMPLETE refresh on a schedule — on a local table.

---

**Some info about ST_GEOMETRY:**

[image]

> The [ST_Geometry](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/what-is-the-st-geometry-storage-type.htm) data type implements the SQL 3 specification of
> user-defined data types (UDTs), allowing you to create columns capable
> of storing spatial data such as the location of a landmark, a street,
> or a parcel of land. It provides International Organization for
> Standards (ISO) and Open Geospatial Consortium, Inc. (OGC) compliant
> structured query language (SQL) access to the geodatabase and
> database. This storage extends the capabilities of the database by
> providing storage for objects (points, lines, and polygons) that
> represent geographic features. It was designed to make efficient use
> of database resources; to be compatible with database features such as
> replication and partitioning; and to provide rapid access to spatial
> data.
>
> ST_Geometry itself is an abstract, noninstantiated superclass.
> However, its subclasses can be instantiated. An instantiated data type
> is one that can be defined as a table column and have values of its
> type inserted into it.

The SQL definition of the user-defined datatype can be found here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=571f701553411d38b3a8305ff74caac4).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SDE."ST_GEOMETRY" (
...
) NOT final
```

*(Although, I'm guessing most of the logic is stored in the EXTPROC.)*

---

**MV object types must be FINAL:**

There is a [known issue](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009568) when trying to create an MV on the ST_GEOMETRY user-defined datatype ([ORA-30373](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1067173_1.html)):

> Creating an Oracle materialized view for a table containing an
> ST_Geometry attribute returns the following error:
>
> ```
> "ORA-30373: object data types are not supported in this context".
>
> Code:
> SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW parcel_view
>   2  AS SELECT * FROM parcel@remote_server;
>
> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW parcel_view
> *
> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-30373: object data types are not supported in this context
> ```
>
> Cause:
>
> Oracle's Advanced Replication functionality requires that **all**
> **object types be defined as FINAL** to participate within a materialized
> view.

> The reason that the ST_Geometry cannot be defined as FINAL is because
> the type contains subtypes used for type inheritance. Oracle does not
> allow a type with subtypes to be defined as FINAL.
>
> Esri is currently working with Oracle to address this issue and
> limitation. The following Oracle TAR file is available for reference:
> "6482996.992 - ORA-30373 MATERIALIZE VIEW UNABLE TO REPLICATE A TYPE
> WHICH CONTAINS SUBTYPES. Enhancement Request (ER) 6370112".

*Note: I've contacted ESRI support and they say there hasn't been any progress with Oracle regarding the enhancement request.*

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to workaround this issue?

- I ask because ESRI has a reputation of not being great with Oracle. So there is a
  chance that they have misunderstood the issue or haven't gotten creative enough.

---

**For example, what about the ONLY keyword?**

[9.9 Materialized View Support for Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/materialized-view-support-for-objects.html#GUID-9CC262CF-7398-400B-8428-E27EF0A0A14A)

> For both object-relational and object materialized views that are
> based on an object **table**, if the type of the master object table
> is not FINAL, the FROM clause in the materialized view definition
> query must include the ONLY keyword.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> CREATE MATERIALIZED
> VIEW customer OF cust_objtyp AS  
> SELECT CustNo FROM ONLY HR.Customer_objtab@dbs1;
> ```
>
> Otherwise, the FROM clause must omit the ONLY keyword.

Notes:

- Unfortunately, that blurb is about object **tables**, not about object **columns** (I believe the ST_GEOMETRY user-defined datatype would be considered
  an "object column").
- But I wonder if the concept of the ONLY keyword could be used to help with
  the FINAL problem with the ST_GEOMETRY object column. Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt there is a work-around, especially if that's what you've already been told by Oracle Support. Defining your query a certain way will not help, as the query *you* write is only actually used once, when the MV is first created. When the full refreshes run, Oracle generates its *own* query behind the scenes, using its own internal rules and optimizations. That query will be *similar* to yours, but will almost certainly not match exactly: hints will disappear, joins may be done differently, some keywords may be dropped or replaced, etc., and you will have *no* control over that.

Comment: Of course, the only way to know for sure is to try it. Have you tried using the "ONLY" keyword, and if so what was the result?

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my test server ambient and worked.

```
SQL> create table test_mv (col1 number not null unique, col2 number);

Table created.

SQL> create materialized view log on test_mv with primary key;

Materialized view log created.

SQL>  create materialized view mv refresh fast on demand as
  2     select col1,col2, sdo_geometry(2001, 26917, sdo_point_type(col1,col2, null), null, null) as shape
  3     from test_mv;

Materialized view created.

SQL> insert into test_mv values (1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL>  insert into test_mv values (2, 2);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> exec dbms_mview.refresh('MV', 'f');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

col1 col2 shape
1   1   (2001, 26917, (1, 1, ), (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ), (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ))
2   2   (2001, 26917, (2, 2, ), (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ), (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ))
```

Comment: Thanks, but that looks like it's using SDO_GEOMETRY (native Oracle datatype). The question is about ST_GEOMETRY (user-defined datatype that is not FINAL).

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my test server.I have created as "COLA_MARKETS" Table using ST_GEOMETRY (TYPE). for the purpose of creating "Materialized View" i have to create view "COLA_MARKETS_VIEW" then create "Materialized View" name as "COLA_MARKETS_MVIEW".

```
CREATE TABLE cola_markets (
  mkt_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(32),
  shape ST_GEOMETRY); 
    
select * from cola_markets;

                           
CREATE VIEW cola_markets_view as select * from cola_markets;    

select * from cola_markets_view;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW cola_markets_mview
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
AS SELECT * From  cola_markets_view;

select * from COLA_MARKETS_MVIEW t;
```